# Google Drive REST Android API V3 Direct Download Url

Tags: android, google-drive-api

**How Do I Get The DIRECT DOWNLOAD URL From Google Drive REST Api V3 Android**

This question is indeed similar to others on topic but never correctly answered

In Google Drive REST api V2 a download url is obtained from the GET request returning a google drive file i.e.

```
File file = mGOOSvc.files().get(fileId).execute();
```

and the Direct download url from

```
String link = file.getDownloadUrl() + "&access_token=" + getAccessToken(mContext) + "alt=media";
```

This stopped working earlier on this year (For some reason??) I was getting the Error 403, so i migrated to Google Drive Rest Api for android V3.

I require a direct access url to use in Exoplayer so as to stream the content directly (Not the input stream i can get this) I can't fathom out how to get this and why it's not working...

From the docs i'm not sure if the access token now needs adding to the request header:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api

also the migration guide states the downloadUrl in V2 becomes files.get with ?alt=media
no examples provided
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v2-to-v3-reference

I have added the scopes to both the GoogleAccountCredential (to sign in and create a Drive Client) and the Google developers console i have also created an OAuth client in the Google Developers Console.

```
DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE, 
DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA, 
DriveScopes.DRIVE
```

I have tried all sorts nothing seems to work.....

```
fun getDownloadUrl(mId: String, mContext: Context): String? {
    val get = service?.files()?.get(mId)
    get?.fields = "*"
    val headers = HttpHeaders()
    headers.authorization = getOAuth2Token(mContext)
    get?.requestHeaders = headers
    get?.oauthToken = getOAuth2Token(mContext)
    get?.alt = "media"
    val request = get?.buildHttpRequest()?.url
    Log.d(TAG, "REQUEST 1 $request")
    Log.d(TAG, "REQUEST 2 $request?alt=media")
    val executeMedia = get?.mediaHttpDownloader?.setDirectDownloadEnabled(true)
    val mDriveFile = get?.execute()
    val test = get?.executeMedia()
    Log.d(TAG, "TEST ${test?.request?.url}")
    Log.d(TAG, "FILE ${mDriveFile?.toPrettyString()}")
    val url = mDriveFile?.webContentLink + "?alt=media"
    val url = mDriveFile?.webContentLink
    Log.d(TAG, "URL $url")
    return url
}
```

The download, read, create and delete methods all works fine but i need the **Direct Link** If anyone can help

Comment: Have you already taking a look at the Java version of [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive)?

Comment: Yea i have already viewed the docs the examples use input/output streams not the direct url to the file

Comment: Thanks Mateo it didn't work for me it turns out the permissions need requesting now to access the files, it doesn't explain this anywhere in the docs...

Comment: Hi ! What do you mean with that? Don't you have your scopes in your script? Were you able to make a ```GET``` request before and now you are not? For the ```GET``` request specifically, remember you will need to give permissions to any of [these scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get#auth). Are you getting any error message? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I believe that for getting the **direct dowload URL link** you need to access the field ```webContentLink``` of the file metadata. When getting the file data with the ```GET``` method, extract the ```webContentLink``` field and I believe that would be your **direct download URL**. For more info check this [site](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads). As I have not tested yet this, **could you please let me know if this suggestion worked and solved your issue?**

Comment: Mateo the Permissions for the file must be created to use the url directly the type must be set and the role https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create

Answer (score -1):

"&access_token=" in request does not work anymore. Instead you need to send the access token in HTTP header like this:

```
Authorization = "Bearer <access_token>"
```